# How to trigger an event when use enter key for html

Tags: javascript, html

I want to send message when I use the enter key but it not working

for my html

```
<form id="form">
    <textarea type="text"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

for my js

```
const sub = document.getElementById('form');

// send message when hit 
sub.addEventListener('submit', send);

// use enter to send message
sub.addEventListener("keypress", (event)=> {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      send();
    }
  });



 function send(event) {
```

Also, I keep getting 'keyCode' is deprecated this error message
This is not working, someone help? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What exactly does not work? Try binding your `keypress` on document itself

Comment: If you are sending the message on enter, that means you aren't using multi-lines. If that is the case, why use textarea? Just use a text input.

Answer (score 0):

I have made adjustment to your code and added the event.preventDefault(). The PreventDefault() is used to prevent the default action belonging to that even from happening.
I Have also used the event.which to get the  keycode of the enter key

```
const sub = document.getElementById('form');

// send message when hit 
sub.addEventListener('submit', send);

// use enter to send message
sub.addEventListener("keypress", (event)=> {
    if (event.which === 13 ) {
//this will prevent the normal behavior of going to a new line when the enter button is pressed
e.preventDefault()
      send();
    }
  });
```